# Add way of "watching" a question during a session in the android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I recently tried out the StackExchange android app. I like it quite a bit. One thing that bugs me though is the lack of a way to watch a question for the duration of your session. This isn't a problem on a computer. I'll see an interesting question with no answers, so I just open the question in a new tab. And then I'll keep browsing the front page and come back later to the tab I opened and refresh and read the answers that were posted to the question.

On the android app, this ability is quite lacking. The best thing I can do is open the question in my browser and go to my browser later.. which kind of defeats the purpose of using the app in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

One nice and simple way for implementing this could be **"recently viewed questions" list,** where each item would have a **pin icon to make them stay on top**.

This should, following the android philosophy, be also remembered thoughout sessions since a "session" isn't really a concept one should have. This said, a way to **unpin all** should be provided, since while the system should not have sessions, the user might (very likely, even) still work in sessions, and thus need an option to fall back to a clean slate.